# Hyper-V cluster with different cpu

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, windows, central-processing-unit

i have these three servers with different CPU :

```
First Server : Intel Xeon E5645 2.4Ghz 12M
Second server : Intel Xeon X5660 2.8Ghz 12M
Third Server : Intel Xeon X5550 2.6Ghz 8M
```

I want to install an hyper-v cluster with these servers.

Is there any issue with this? How to be sure that all features will be functional despite the different cpu?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just to be clear: The Hyper-V Role and the Failover Clustering Feature are two separate components. You don't install a Hyper-V Cluster, you install the Hyper-V Role and you install the Failover Clustering Feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem having different CPUs across hosts. If you plan to live migrate VMs between the hosts, you will need to check the box under the Processor Compatibility section in the settings menu for the VM.

http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2013/04/windows-server-2012-hyper-v-configure-vm-processor-compatibility-via-powershell/

Comment: +1 Need to check that box. It also limits the CPU extensions guests can use, but that's typically not an issue.

Comment: @ChrisS Could you please explain how the limits would function? The article only states that the CPUs have to be of the same generation, dont think it mentions # of cores. I also have a similar situation with a mix of 1 x 16 core and a 2 x 12 core servers - all of them however the same socket / chipset. I would like to know what is the max CPU cores per VM that I would be able to assign. Thanks.