# Can I backup a VHD to an identical system and boot in case of hardware failure on the original?

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, hyper-v, restore

Pretty much all in the title.  I'm already using Hyperoo to backup the vhd file to a identical server and was wondering if it would be possible to add the vhd file to a Hyper-V virtual machine and boot it on system 2.

I've actually booted it once after getting a boot error, but know there's probably pitfalls, especially since the virtual machine in question is a server 2008 r2 installation.

Comment: What are the Host OS's? Have you considered setting up clustering for automatic failover? Having identical hardware isn't even an issue if you do it correctly, see http://serverfault.com/questions/598050/hyper-v-cluster-with-different-cpu, for example.

Comment: Host OS is also Server 2008 R2.  I'll check out the link.  Thanks for comment!